# Are measurable under product outer measure sets a cartesian product of measurable sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If we define the outer product measure like this :
$$
\mu*\nu(E) =\inf\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)\nu(B_i)\mid  E\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\times B_i,\ \text{$A_i$ is $\mu$- measurable, $B_i$ is $\nu$-measurable}\}.
$$
Is it true that if that whenever $E=A\times B\subset X\times Y$ is $\mu*\nu$-measurable, then $A\subset X$ is $\mu$-measurable and $B\subset Y$ is $\nu$-measurable?
If it's not true, then what would the counterexample be? I don't know where to start.

The other way around it's easy to show, I was able to prove it, moreover $\mu*\nu(A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are $\mu$ and $\nu$-measurable respectively.

Comment: No. It is not true. Let $A$ be any NON-measurable subset of $X$ and let $B$ be any measurable subset of $Y$, such $\nu(B)=0$.  Then $A\times B$ is $\mu*\nu$-measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not true. Let $A$ be any NON-measurable subset of $X$ and let $B$ be any measurable subset of $Y$, such $\nu(B)=0$. Then $A \times B$ is $\mu*\nu$-measurable.

More details: Let us prove that $A \times B$ is $\mu*\nu$-measurable.  Let $\mu^*(A)$ be the outer measure of $A$. Then, $\mu*\nu(A \times B)$ the outer product measure of $A \times B$, satisfies: 
$$ \mu*\nu(A \times B)= \mu^*(A).\nu(B)=0 $$
Since $\mu*\nu(A \times B)=0$, we have that $A \times B$ is $\mu*\nu$-measurable.

Comment: I don't really follow why such cartesian product would be measurable. Could you explain with a bit more details?

Comment: @Proton I have added a more detailed explanation to the answer. Please, let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Ah right, zero measure sets would indeed be measurable, I didn't notice this fact. Silly me :) Now everything is clear. Thank you!